# Exchange of integral and derivative in complex anaylsis

Tags: real-analysis

In the book "Function Theory of One Complex Variable, R.Greene, S.Krantz", I saw the following (Exercise 3 in Chapter 3):

> Explain why the following string of equalities is incorrect:
>   $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \int_{-1}^{1} \log |x-t| dt = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log |x-t| dt = \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{-1}{(x-t)^2}dt.$$

I tried to find a proper reason, but I couldn't find any satisfying solution.

Especially, I don't know why the second equality is incorrect. I think that
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log |x-t| dt = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\pm1}{|x-t|}dt= \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x-t}dt=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{-1}{(x-t)^2}dt.$$
Where am I wrong?

Comment: In fact, it is a problem of **real** analysis.

Comment: The condition of continuity of the integrand is not met ([see the theorem].(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)).

Comment: Do you mean that because $\log|x-t|$ is not continuous in $\mathbb{R} \times [-1,1]$, we can't exchange the derivative and integration?

Comment: Yes. And I just saw that the answer of @
user10000100_u is exactly the same.

Comment: [Complex analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) is about $f(z)$ and $f'(z)$ where **$z $ is the complex variable**

Comment: Yes I see. Because I think $x\in \mathbb{C}$ I made the tag "Complex analysis". But maybe I need to consider $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Thank you. JeanMarie and user1952009

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem.** Let $g : J\times I\to \mathbf{R}$ be a function where $I$ and $J$ are (real) intervals. Suppose that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} (x,t)$ exists on $J\times I$ and that :

- $\forall x\in J$ the application $t\mapsto g(x,t)$ is piecewise continuous and integrable on $I$
- $\forall x\in J$ the application $t\mapsto\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} (x,t)$ is piecewise continuous on $I$
- $\forall t\in I$ the map $x\mapsto\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} (x,t)$ is continuous on $J$
- for each $[a,b]\subseteq J$ there exists $\varphi : [a,b]\to \mathbf{R}$ piecewise continuous, positive and integrable on $I$ such that $\forall x\in[a,b], \forall t\in I, \left|\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} (x,t)\right| \leq \varphi(t)$

then $t\mapsto\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} (x,t)$ is integrable on $I$ for all $x\in J$ and the application $x\mapsto \int_I g(x,t)dt$ is of class $\mathscr{C}^1$ on $J$ with derivative equals to $x\mapsto \int_I \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} (x,t)dt$.

**Non-application.** In your case, you cannot apply this theorem as even the continuity condition is not verified...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to validate it as an answer if you happen being fine with it, or to ask for precisions if needed.